# Creating a SQL Server Report using a programatically generated dataset

Tags: .net, reporting-services

I have a SQL Server Local Report which contains content for around 5000 pages (with images on almost every row).
Currently i build out the dataset using multiple calls to the database, since getting all the data at once is causing time-out issues. 
It is currently taking a really long time (around 10 minutes) to Render the report to a pdf using the Render method in a local report. I've read that using Local Reports for a large amount of data isn't efficient and usually will take a longer amount of time to process. Is there any way i can convert this local report to a server report (keeping in mind that I need to build out the dataset dynamically)? 
Will i see a huge difference in the amount of time it takes to generate the report if i do convert it?

Edit: The requirement is that this needs to be an on-demand report.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

One option that will require no change in code is to schedule your report to run using the SSRS scheduler at a set time (maybe late at night) and publish the report to a file share or email it in pdf format. However if you're trying to run on demand, this suggestion may not help. SSRS scheduling is handy for this sort of thing.

Comment: I should have specified that it needs to be an on demand report. Sorry about that.

Comment: Hmmm have you tried doing the bulk of your work on SQL server and then dropping this data into, for lack of a better word, a "permanent-temp" table. I.e. let sql server do the heavy lifting of getting all the data you need - clear this holding table, dump the data in there, and let your SSRS report simply query this table i.e a simple select so it doesn't have to do much work? I did this once when i was pulling data from SQL Server and Db2, I wrote a proc that would do the combining for me and let the SSRS report simply do a blind select on my hold table...

Comment: hmm interesting way of going at it. I'll attempt this and see if it works out. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

If you have 5000 pages in a report, it's not a report. No one will look through 5000 pages, and in fact 100 pages is considered excessive.

Make a condensed report, like a table of contents with summary totals, and use it as a navigation tool so you can click on a summary item and load up the details in a Detail report that takes some values like a customer_id as a parameter.

Reasons:

1. No one will ever wait for your report to load
2. When was the last time you read a 5000 page "report" lol... you might as well give them the raw table in a zip file.
3. Memory restrictions in ASP.Net (2GB for 32Bit systems). Avoid "Out Of Memory" Errors.
4. This will never EVER be able to be used in an email as an attachment. It's gonna be way over typical max of 10MB once exported.
5. I've made over 120 Reports in SSRS, I've been there and done that so I'm telling you from experience so you avoid even more problems in the future. I've gone as far as to completely write my own report server UI replacement with a graphical tree structure and tons of extra buttons and features as well as my own command line report server with proper logging so we can verify when emails don't go out and why, and re-direct scheduled emails with bogus email addresses etc...
6. Add proper sql indexes, something is not right if it's taking 10 Mins.

Do This:

```
Main Report:
Customer1 $1,000
Customer2 $2,000
All Customers: $5,000
```

SubReport (getting the cust_id parameter passed to it):

```
Customer 1 $1000
  Order1: $500
    Item1: Socks
    Item2: Shoes
  Order2: $500
```

Note: When I say "SubReport" I don't mean the one in the toolbox. I mean a separate report that takes customer_id as a parameter and a "Navigation Link" from some textbox in the Main Report that's passing the current customer into the subreport's parameter.

What you should really be doing instead of doing what your boss tells you is cutting to the chase and asking WHAT he really needs answered. Obviously someone is looking through something to find a particular answer, he's not realizing the computer can do this FOR HIM. So he wants to feel all warm and fuzzy printing pages all day. It's always better to make a few specialized reports to answer specific questions for people from specific departments etc... instead of a one size fits all. This avoid people telling you later on to add or remove a column, then the other guy coming back and complaining endlessly.

Inventory is a good example of this. Salesmen need and inventory with quantities and detailed listings, Financial auditors need dollar values and the age of the items in a condensed form.